# Write sql insert and update queries while saving or updating in h2 database programatically

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to create a local project for my learning purpose in which I am using `h2` as in-memory database.
I am using `spring-jpa` for my project.

I was wondering is there any way we can take dump of data or writing logs (in this case queries) in a file.

Why do I need this?
so, as h2 is an in-memory database, whenever project ends it deletes all the data.
what I want to get all the data when I re-run the process again.
Tried on searching on internet couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using H2, which is *solely* in-memory, consider using [SQLite](https://sqlite.org), which can create a file and will be left behind after the application is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

H2 is not an in-memory database system, H2 supports both persistent and in-memory databases. If you need to preserve your data, use file-based database with `jdbc:h2:./somename` URL, where `./somename` is relative (must starts with `./`) or absolute path to the database file without extension.
https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url

Of course, you can export your data into external file even if you use an in-memory database with `SCRIPT TO 'filename.sql'` command of H2, but there are no good reasons to use that functionality together with in-memory database instead of persistent one. Such dumps are usually used for migration.